# How do I convert a string into an algebraic or transcendental function in Python?

Tags: python, wxpython

This code is a wxglade code & it takes the input of a text box whis is a algebraic or transcendental function

```
 def event_2(self, event): # wxGlade: application.<event_handler>
        #print "Event handler `event_2' not implemented!"
        #event.Skip()
    equationString = self.text_ctrl_1.GetValue()
    function = eval(equationString)
    event.Skip()
```

it gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ppy.py", line 103, in event_2
    function = eval(equationString)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever Python code you've put in text_ctrl_1 refers to a variable d that wasn't defined. Python does not understand algebra or symbolic math; if you pass a string like `x = y + 3` to `eval` and either `x` or `y` are not defined Python will throw an error.

There are, however, libraries to do symbolic math in Python. If you want to use symbolic math in Python, look in to [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/).